# Error trying to attach an image to an Azure DevOps wiki page

Tags: azure, attachment, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

I have successfully used the Azure DevOps API to create multiple wiki pages, via a standalone C# desktop app. Now I'm trying to attach an image (currently stored locally) to the wiki (as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), but get an error

> The wiki attachment creation failed with message : The input is not a
> valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than
> two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding
> characters.

This is the code that I use to read the image file and convert it to a Base64 string - is this correct?

```
string base64String = null; 
string img = File.ReadAllText(att.Value); 
byte[] byteCredentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(img); 
base64String= Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials);
```

Then I create the "content" for the API call as

```
string data = @"{""content"": """ + base64String + @"""}";
```

and run the API call

```
string url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wikiIdentifier}/attachments?name=Image.png&api-version=6.0";
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
request.Method = "PUT";
request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{1}", "AzurePAT"))));

if (data != null)
{
     using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
     {
           writer.Write(data);
     }
}

HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

string result = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
     result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with any of this? The concept of setting up a "content" JSON with an encoded Base64 string doesn't seem to be documented, so have I done it correctly?

Any help or advice gladly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image file does not contain text, it is a binary file, calling `File.ReadAllText` probably messes up the encoding. Try:

```cs
var img = File.ReadAllBytes(att.Value);
var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(img);
```

In addition, the request expects the body to just be a string. You are passing JSON. Your code should look like this:

```cs
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    writer.Write(base64String);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives exactly the same error

Comment: I'm pretty sure you aren't formatting your body right. The stream is supposed to be the entire body content, but in stead you wrap it in some json. A json request with a content-type "application/octet-stream" isn't valid anyway.

Comment: Request Body
Media Types: "application/octet-stream"

REQUEST BODY
Name Type Description
body 
string
Stream to upload

Comment: From the Microsoft link in my original question, this is all that is listed for the body, with no example

Request Body
Media Types: "application/octet-stream"

REQUEST BODY
Name Type Description
body string      Stream to upload
I wish I could find an example of what it should be

Comment: I am pretty sure your body should just be your Base64 string, so not wrapped in JSON as you have done since this wouldn't match with the header.

Comment: Thank you, just passing the Base64 string in via the variable data successfully uploaded the attachment - amazing! Thanks for your help